# Problem adding Values in Array in coolectionView - Swift

Tags: swift

I pull data from the database. I am separating the data I have taken according to the number of CATEGORIDAVTOPLAM.count. For example, there is 4 data in the first section and 3 data in the second section. However, while the data in 2.section should be 5.6.7 items in the new DavFile array, 1.2.7 in Array. attracts the next data. How can I add data by counting in the section in a single directory? When I do as follows, I have 7 data in total as follows. The ranking in the first section is 1.2.3.4 in Array, and the ranking in the second section is 1.2.7. values.

```
   func getIndexForArray(with indexPath:IndexPath)->Int{
        var itemIndex = 0
          if indexPath.row != 0{
              for _ in 0..<indexPath.section{
                  itemIndex += (sonsuzCollec.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1)
              }
              return (itemIndex + indexPath.row)
          }else{
              return indexPath.row
          }
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return  Int(KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM[section]) ?? 0 }
     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return yeniDavKATIsımNew.count }
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellSonsuz", for: indexPath) as! sonsuzCell
  let currentIndex = getIndexForArray(with: indexPath)
              if currentIndex < yeniDavFile.count{
                 let urlNew = URL(string: yeniDavFile[currentIndex])
                 cell.davetiyeFoto.sd_setImage(with: urlNew)       
                 return cell
             }else{
                return UICollectionViewCell()
             }

 @objc func kategoriSaydırNew(){
...
             if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                     for review in baslik {
                        if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                              let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                               self.yeniDavFile.append(s)
                    } }  
                         DispatchQueue.main.async { self.sonsuzCollec.reloadData() }}
         if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                            for review in baslik {
                            if let soru_baslik = review["TOPLAM"] as? Int {
                            let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                                self.KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM.append(s)


                                } }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                   self.sonsuzCollec.reloadData()
                                                                         }
```

Comment: Can you share example of the data and how you want to display them?